# Autolayout UILabel inside a UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, autolayout, uilabel

I have a UIView and inside that there is a subview which is UIView again, inside that UIView i want to add a UILabel at the centre , I am using Autolayout. I have added all the constraints to all the views , but UILabel at the centre is only visible on iPad screens, it goes missing on smaller screen, my doubt is, when its coordinates, when are calculated on resized parent UIView, turns out to be wrong or it gets squeezed so much that it becomes invisible.

Please help me on this, I am not an expert in auto layout so obvious.
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Also the outer UIView will be presented fullscreen in parent ViewController

Comment: whats your constraints on all the views.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari updated with constraints

Comment: Whenever you are applying constraints and want the layout to be fit in every device, never give any hard coded constraints like View.bottom + 280 as I can see in your pic. From bottom + 280 means that in smaller iPhones this view will just go up. In order to solve these, we can use equal width,height or aspect ratio

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari have tried with aspect ration for parent view still same thing was happening

Comment: Posted my constraints and solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my constraints
[image]

And this is my Layout in all screens

[image]

Where your label is centered and also the Black View is increasing height with aspect ratio as per the device's height

Comment: can you guide me how to adde align vertical constraints on label ?

Comment: If it helps please accept as a tick. Just right click or control click drag on label towards its parent view and make the constraints center vertically .i have created a complete autolayout series on youtube. You can get your hands on autolayout from there too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGeBiWUiYnI

Comment: Oh man i forgot this , thing back on iOS age 6 months almost , thanks it helped.

Answer (score 1):

set leading,trailing,horizontal center in container and top constrain to label with it's container view.

Answer (score 0):

You should align it horizontally in the container.and also no one will be able to help unless you show all the constraints.

Comment: align horizontally only will not work as he had already put contraints acc to iPAd. which will make the UI hell in iPhone 4s or 5

Comment: @fahadkhan all the constraints are added in second image